# Unable to install Plugins in Jenkins deployed in Docker

Tags: java, docker, ssl, jenkins, sslhandshakeexception

I was successfully able to install Jenkins using the latest official image https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins and added the https://repo.jenkins-ci.org, https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/, https://updates.jenkins.io/, https://www.jenkins.io/ SSL Certificates to cacerts of jenkins and jdk and provided the cacerts path to JAVA_OPTS but I still get the below exception

> hudson.PluginManager#doCheckUpdatesServer: Error checking update sites for 1 attempt(s). Last exception was: SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Below is my compose file

```
version: '3.7'
services: 
    jenkins:
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
        privileged: true
        user: root
        environment: 
            JAVA_OPTS: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/jenkins_home/keystore/cacerts -Dhudson.model.UpdateCenter.pluginDownloadReadTimeoutSeconds=120
        ports: 
            - 8080:8080
            - 50000:50000
        volumes:
            - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
volumes:
    jenkins_home:
```

Certificates added to cacerts

```
root@**************:/# keytool -list -v -keystore $JENKINS_HOME/keystore/cacerts | grep jenkins
Enter keystore password:  **************
Alias name: https://repo.jenkins-ci.org
Owner: CN=repo.jenkins-ci.org
  DNSName: repo.jenkins-ci.org
Alias name: https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/
Owner: CN=updates.jenkins-ci.org
  DNSName: updates.jenkins-ci.org
Alias name: https://updates.jenkins.io/
Owner: CN=updates.jenkins.io
  DNSName: updates.jenkins.io
Alias name: https://www.jenkins.io/
Owner: CN=jenkins.io
  DNSName: jenkins.io
root@**************:/#
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that the TLS client cannot find a path from the X.509 certificate presented by the server during TLS handshake to any of the X.509 certificates in the truststore. Either you are missing something there, or you are not using the truststore you think you are using. You can check which truststore is used with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake`.

Comment: Hello @automatictest, thanks very much for your help. Found that my org was adding few additional SSL certs which I was supposed to install in the docker container